# Unit testing and faking static method using Moq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

Here is the scenario-

Class 1 is helper class :

```
class Helper
{
    IInterface abc
    {
        // some code in get and set
        get;set;
    }
    public static string Method1(){
        return abc.method();
    }
}
```

Now I have a controller class that have an action method:

```
public virtual string GetStrFromMethod
{
    get 
    {
        return Helper.Method1();
    }
}

public ViewResult Action() {
    // here I am calling Method1 like this
    var str = GetStrFromMethod;
}
```

Now I want to fake the virtual property from test class and hence I am doing this :

```
var mock = new Moq<ControllerClass>();
mock.SetupGet(x => x.GetStrFromMethod).Returns("str");
```

When I run this test, I am expecting when the action looks for property GetStrFromMethod , it should return fake value set in moq test. But I am getting following error in helper class abc propertry:

"The catalog of assemblies have not been set up."

I know one way to fake static method is to wrap in virtual method which I have done. What am I missing here ?

Comment: Use fakes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: I don't actually see any `static` in your code samples

Comment: Fakes doesn't work in vs 2010.

Comment: Your code is full of errors, and you don’t show your actual test code. If you mock the getter that uses a static member to skip accessing that static member, then you don’t need to worry about that static call at all.

Comment: That looks OK, maybe you can post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?